# Visual Studio Error List code URL

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I created a MSBuild task that reports errors and warnings that correctly get displayed in Visual Studio's Error List window. The strings in the Codes columns are clickable, and when I click on a C# compiler code, like CS0246, I get taken to a bing search for that code. However, when I click on my own code, say ZIV0001, I just get sent to a MSDN url, which redirects to the Visual Studio documentation page on learn.microsoft.com.

How can I make clicks on my error codes go to a web search or a custom URL?